# Is this sum right represented for the case $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, summation

if $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{k}{n} x^n $ then $g(0)=1$ ?
I am confused, isn't it supposed to yield $0^0$ as a factor in the first term (which would be an indefinition at least, for this context)? if $g(0)=1$ Wouldn't it be "better" to just define $g(x)=1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{k}{n} x^n $ for $x=0$?

Comment: this not correct $g(x)=1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \binom{k}{n}x^k$ $\\$for x=0

Comment: In this context $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: $x^0=1$ identically, both algebraically and analytically, so there is no issue.

Comment: As an afterthought, while this implies there's no mathematical difference, there arguably is a _pedagogical_ difference between the two forms.  Which form is _pedagogically better_ is a separate question but one that is likely to result in opinion-based answers.